# Angular child routes reload parent component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm going to give a lot of background (maybe unnecessary) because I don't really know how to ask this question.

I have an Angular asset tracking application with routing that has some parent routes and several child routes. The child routes all specify the parent component and activate different components within that component (see code).

The parent component generates a tree with several router links to the detail pages of the various assets grouped by location and type and the user navigates through this tree to select an asset. However, when the router link is activated, it reloads the parent component, and subsequently the tree, and now the user is left at the starting point and has to open the tree all over again.

I'm trying to determine if I've architected the component relationships wrong or if I'm coming at this workflow from the wrong angle all together.

Essentially, what I am trying to make happen is the tree structure remains in-tact while the user navigates to different places within the parent component. Regardless if it's the details page, dashboard, etc.

How can I prevent the parent component from being reloaded every time a child router link is activated and deactivated?

app-routing.module.ts code:

```
{
    path: 'assets',
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard],
    children: [
         {
            path: '',
            component: AssetsComponent,
         },
         {
            path: 'details/:asset',
            component: AssetsComponent
         },
    ]
},
```

asset.component.ts code:

```
<div>
    <div class="select-pane">
        ... 
        <div class="asset-list-item lvl-3" routerLink="/assets/details/{{ assetList?.hostname }}" routerLinkActive="selected">{{ assetList?.hostname }}</div>
        ... 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog-pane">
    <app-asset-dashboard *ngIf="!currentAsset"></app-asset-dashboard>
    <app-asset-detail *ngIf="currentAsset" [asset]="currentAsset">
```

Comment: My understanding from the question is, `AssetComponent` is handling both display of the tree and the details. In that case, after navigating to `/details`, the component is reloading. My suggestion is, have the details in a separate component, say `AssetDetailsComponent` and have it render in a `<router-outlet>` inside the `AssetComponent`

Comment: Yes, the AssetComponent displays a tree and then I have two other components, AssetDetailsComponent and AssetDashboardComponent. Navigation to /details/'some-asset' reloads the entire AssetComponent which is undesired. Would I put `<router-outlet>` in the AssetComponent then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `AssetComponent` is handling both  `''` and `/details` routes, when you navigate to `/details`, the component is loading again with the tree reset. I suggest, you structure the app this way:

Also, I think you need `pathMatch:full` in the `''` route, but I'm entirely sure if this solves anything.

```
{
    path: 'assets',
    component: AssetsComponent,
    canActivate: [ 
    AuthGuard
    ],
    children: [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: AssetDashboardComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'details/:asset',
        component: AssetDetailComponent,
    },
    ]
},
```

AssetComponent Template should look something like:

```
<div>existing component template that has tree</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

AssetDetailsComponent Template should look like:

```
<div>Asset details are moved here </div>
```

The respective component classes for each of the component will have the data and functions moved in them.

Comment: I tried this and this is where I think I've architected this app wrong from the start. Or perhaps my issue wasn't clear. The AssetsComponent contains different HTML panes. The "side pane" displays the tree and I want the "dialog pane" to update with either the details component or the dashboard component. I want the side pane to be displayed all the time regardless of the selected route.

Comment: You probably want that tree/nav as another component and included using the selector inside the AssetComponent template. Let me edit the answer and include that part for you.

Comment: I was able to get this working and I updated the answer to show the routing I used. I added the parent component to the parent route and added a redirect to the dashboard which in turn loads the dashboard component. I added a router outlet to the AssetsComponent as shown and this all works as expected now! Thank you for your guidance @Aragorn